Can't see list of files in conficts to fix on GitLab
Hello,
I created a PR on GitLab but there are conflicts I have to fix.
Unfortunately, I can't use the UI to fix, it must be locally but I can't see a list with files in conflicts:

When I clist on "Resolve locally", there is nothing usefull for me:

How can I know files related to the conflict?
Thanks
I try to fond the list of files which qre on conflict to fix the pull request.
